# Change label size in OpenLayers 3 from QGIS Plugin output

Tags: geojson, labeling, openlayers, qgis-openlayers-plugin, zoom

I am working on OpenLayers 3 at the moment and my aim is to provide an offline map.

At the moment I am trying to get GeoJSON files offline. For that I am using the QGIS Plugin that exports the Shapefiles from QGIS into an OpenLayers Web Page. My problem is that the labels for the roads keep the same size when I am zooming in and out which leads to a messy output.

Does anyone know how to change it? I found some pages where it was proposed to use map.getscale() but I wasn't able to embedd it into the code.

I guess this is the part of the code which needs to be changed:

```
                var styleCache_roads={}
                var style_roads = function(feature, resolution){
                    var value = ""
                    var style = [ new ol.style.Style({
                        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: "rgba(76,38,0,1.0)", lineDash: null, width: 1})
                    })
                    ,new ol.style.Style({
                        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: "rgba(255,206,128,1.0)", lineDash: null, width: 1})
                    })
                    ];
                    var labelText = feature.get("name");
                    var key = value + "_" + labelText

                    if (!styleCache_roads[key]){
                        var text = new ol.style.Text({
                              font: '9.0px Calibri,sans-serif',
                              text: labelText,
                              fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 255)"
                              }),
                            });
                        styleCache_roads[key] = new ol.style.Style({"text": text});
                    }
                    var allStyles = [styleCache_roads[key]];
                    allStyles.push.apply(allStyles, style);
                    return allStyles;
                };
```

Comment: I don't know how to make labels a fixed size in map units in an OL3 vector layer. Is a raster layer an option? You could make a tiled basemap.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I will consider it. Best, Hannah

Answer (score -2):

ol.style.Text has the property scale,best use with resolution or map zoom

Comment: This may answer the question, but it's best to include an explanation of why and an example.